# Environment variables locally and Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra, environment-variables, gitignore, foreman

I have a sinatra app in which i have a yml file to set environment variables, i call them using this method

```
module MyConfig

 def config
  environment = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
  YAML.load_file("./config/config.yml")[environment]
 end
 end
```

so when i want to use a variable i do this for example

```
aws_access_key_id = config['aws_access_key']
```

I have a .gitignore file that ignores config.yml when pushing to github for example.So when  I push to heroku these environment variables will not be accessible?

So this leaves me with using the heroku way of setting them like so

```
heroku config:add aws_access_key= myapikey
```

but heroku accesses these like

```
aws_access_key_id = ENV['aws_access_key']
```

How can i set my dev environment to use method config and heroku use ENV, am i looking at this the wrong way? or does my config method do this for me?

Any help appreciated

RAKEFILE

```
  require 'active_support/core_ext'
  require './config/config.rb'
  require 'bundler/setup'
  Bundler.require(:default)

   include MyConfig

  AssetSync.configure do |con|
  con.fog_provider = 'AWS'
  con.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
  con.fog_directory = config['fog_directory']
  con.aws_access_key_id = config['aws_access_key']
  con.aws_secret_access_key = config['aws_secret_key']
  con.prefix = "assets"
  con.public_path = Pathname("./public")
  end

 namespace :assets do
 desc "Precompile assets"
 task :precompile do
  AssetSync.sync
 end
end
```

Answer (score 19):

**Update:**

I now use the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem instead of the example below. So instead of ignoring the `env.rb` file, I now ignore the `.env` file with Git.

**Original post:**

Try this,

```
# /env.rb

ENV['aws_bucket'] = 'my_bucket'
ENV['aws_access_key'] = 'my_access_key'
ENV['aws_access_secret'] = 'my_access_secret'
```

This file sets the same `ENV` values as `heroku config` would do.

```
# /config.rb

require './env' if File.exists?('env.rb')
```

The `env.rb` will only get required if it exists.

```
# /.gitignore

/env.rb
```

The `env.rb` has been added to the `.gitignore` file so it isn't kept in Git.

You would then access the values using `ENV['key']` instead of `config['key']`.

You might need to change the path to the `env.rb` if it's not in the same directory as the `config.rb` file.

**EDIT:**

From looking at your `Rakefile` in the previous question, you need to change it to this:

```
# Rakefile

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)
require './env' if File.exists?('env.rb')

AssetSync.configure do |con|
 con.fog_provider = 'AWS'
 con.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
 con.fog_directory = ENV['aws_bucket']
 con.aws_access_key_id = ENV['aws_access_key']
 con.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['aws_access_secret']
 con.prefix = "assets"
 con.public_path = Pathname("./public")
end

namespace :assets do
  desc "Precompile assets"
  task :precompile do
    AssetSync.sync
  end
end
```

I've assumed that the only method in `/config/config.rb` was the `config` method so I've removed the,

```
require './config/config.rb'
include MyConfig
```

And swapped the `config[key]` for the `ENV[key]` values defined in `env.rb`. You may need to change the `key` names to match up.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Sam, this time after running heroku run rake assets:precompile I get No such file or directory - /config/config.yml, which i understand as it is in the .gitignore file? any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Try removing `YAML.load_file("./config/config.yml")[environment]`. Since you have replaced the YAML file with the `env.rb` file, you no longer need to include it.

Comment: yes i tried that but then i get undefined method or local variable config, as my rake file calls the method, ive posted the rakefile

Comment: You will have to move all your YAML `config[key]` properties into `env.rb` and change them to `ENV[key]` properties. Then remove all references to the `config[key]` method in `MyConfig`.

Comment: thanks very much, so if i wasnt going to use heroku i could stick with the config.yml way, but then again your method works just aswell even if i didnt use heroku

Comment: Yes, I think the YAML way is cleaner if you can symlink on the server. Heroku uses ENV for it's config and doesn't allow symlinking, so the `env.rb` is more suitable here.

Comment: almost there, error now warning: already initialized constant VALID_CHARACTER, after some reading i cant see anything wrong with my variables, im assuming there is no issue with ENV?

Comment: Have you defined `VALID_CHARACTER` twice maybe? Possibly in different files? That error means the ruby constant named `VALID_CHARACTER` has been defined more than once. A ruby constant should only be defined once and shouldn't change.

Comment: i cant even see it defined Once

Comment: Try dropping the lines, `require 'active_support/core_ext'` and `require 'asset_sync'`. The Gemfile should be requiring these already. Answer updated.

Comment: still get warning: already initialized constant VALID_CHARACTER, fog_directory cant be blank

Comment: Does your `ENV[]` key in the `rakefile` match the key in  the `env.rb` file for the bucket?

Comment: ENV['aws_bucket'] = 'applecatering' (env) and con.fog_directory = ENV['aws_bucket'] (rakefile)

Comment: i have my env.rb file in this structure config/env.rb so this is correct ye? require './env' if File.exists?('env.rb')

Comment: Ah! Add `require './config/env' if File.exists?('config/env.rb')` to the `Rakefile`. It was removed when `config.rb` was removed.

Comment: I'm out of ideas for now. Might have to come back to this later. `VALID_CHARACTER` is a contant in ActiveSupport and I think it's being defined twice but I'm not sure why.

Comment: ok so in my gemfile i have gem 'activesupport', require: 'active_support', activesupport comes as default doesnt it?

Comment: i have uninstalled gem activesupport and then re run bundle without this in the gemfile, still same problem

Comment: I would suggest ignoring the warning message. AssetSync has `activesupport` in it's gemspec so that's getting included any way. It seems to be conflicting with the constant defined in the `mail` gem from the `pony` gemspec. If you remove the 'pony' gem, the warning will stop. Are there any other error messages after the `pony` gem is removed?

Comment: thanks sam, but i need the pony gem for my mailer, ill try it just to see if message does infact go away but what then?

Comment: rake command for heroku doesnt compile anything? just starts the rake and then goes back to terminal ready for new command

Comment: actually just checked my aws account and last update was yesterday, not the rake task i just completed

Comment: Thank you! In my case, Heroku uses the config.ru (.ru ext)

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the yaml, and describe the environment variables in a `.env` file then start your app with `foreman start`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup

---

Or keep your hybrid system, where you load a yaml in dev, and use environment variables on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar to Sam's suggestion, but a little bit different. I have a YAML config file too, but I wrap the reading of it in a Rake task, which then runs the app.

```
# in the Rakefile

require 'yaml'

def set_connstring
  s = %Q!postgres://#{ENV["DB_APP"]}@localhost/#{ENV["DB_APP"]}!
  ENV['DATABASE_URL'] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "test" ? "#{s}.test" : s
end


def basic_environment
  warn "  Setting up environment..."

  file = File.expand_path( File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), "./config.yml" )
  if File.exist? file
    YAML.load_file(file).each do |k,v|
      warn "-> #{k}"
      ENV[k.upcase] = v
    end
  end

  set_connstring()
end

namespace :app do

  desc "Set up the environment locally"
  task :environment do
    basic_environment()
  end

  desc "Run the app locally"
  task :run_local => "app:environment" do
    exec "bin/rackup config.ru -p #{ENV['RUN_LOCAL_PORT']}"
  end
end
```

It means I can run it locally without any code inside the app to deal with this.

---

Edit: a quick aside, I notice you have `Bundler.require(:default)` in your Rakefile. If you use `bundle install --binstubs` then Bundler installs all executables into a dir named "bin/" within the project. Then, if you run any of those executables they automatically use the libraries installed by Bundler, no need to require via Bundler. See http://gembundler.com/v1.2/man/bundle-exec.1.html.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting directly from heroku admin:
Settings -> Reveal Config Vars

Then open browser js console, paste this and type enter...

```
k=[];
$(".config-var-list input").map(function(y, x){k.push($(x).val())});
v=[];
$(".config-var-list textarea").map(function(y, x){v.push($(x).val())});
ret="";
k.map(function(x, i){ret+=k[i]+"\t"+v[2*i]+"\n"});
console.info(ret);
```