# ENV variables not being read sinatra

Tags: heroku, sinatra, environment-variables, activesupport

So i am trying to serve my static assets from Amazon s3 locally and for Heroku, I was loading a yml file but that doesn't work as Heroku doesn't accept symlinks.

So i was given the suggestion to use ENV variables as Heroku also uses these. I have a rake task to precompile the assets to AWS. two problems at the moment

1) My ENV variables are not being read.(Fog directory can't be blank, Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank

2) When running a rake task i also get the error 'already initialized constant VALID_CHARACTER'

So the activesupport constant is being loaded twice?

My setup

env.rb

```
ENV['aws_bucket'] = 'bucketname'
ENV['aws_access_key'] = 'myaccesskey'
ENV['aws_secret_key'] = 'mysecretkey'
```

Rakefile

```
require 'bundler/setup'
 Bundler.require(:default)
 require './env' if File.exists?('env.rb')


AssetSync.configure do |con|
con.fog_provider = 'AWS'
con.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
con.fog_directory = ENV['aws_bucket']
con.aws_access_key_id = ENV['aws_access_key']
con.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['aws_secret_key']
con.prefix = "assets"
con.public_path = Pathname("./public")   
end

namespace :assets do
 desc "Precompile assets"
task :precompile do
AssetSync.sync
end
```

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'pony'
gem 'sinatra-flash'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'asset_sync', git: 'git://github.com/ejholmes/asset_sync.git', branch: 'sinatra'
```

UPDATE

AssetSync has activesupport in it's gemspec so that's getting included any way. It seems to be conflicting with the constant defined in the mail gem from the pony gemspec.

So with the Pony gem removed i can precompile assets locally, but when i try and compile for heroku nothing happens, it starts the rake task but then just goes back to the terminal ready for a new command.

The other thing is i need Pony for my mailer, how can i get around this?

Comment: you set the ENV vars through the heroku tool iirc.

Comment: Ah so even though i am setting ENV in app heroku doesn't read them

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @Richlewis, yes, ENV vars as in shell vars not just app vars :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the clash between Pony and when running Rake locally, [put the gems into different groups](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/), e.g.

```
# Gemfile
group :assets do
  gem 'asset_sync', git: 'git://github.com/ejholmes/asset_sync.git', branch: 'sinatra'
end

group :mail do
  gem "pony"
end

# more…
```

in the Rakefile

```
Bundler.require(:assets,:database,:whatever_else_you_need)
```

in the rackup/app file

```
Bundler.require(default,:assets,:database,:mail,:whatever_else_you_need)
```

As to your other problem, you should set the env vars for production via `heroku config` (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) and load them locally using the Rakefile [as I said in the other question you asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466627/environment-variables-locally-and-heroku). The env vars will live for the extent of the Ruby process, so if you load them in via Rake and *also* start the local server within the same Rake process you'll get Sinatra picking up all the env vars.

---

Edit: env vars will last as long as the process that added them, so if you put them in a dependent task the following task will have access to them:

```
namespace :assets do

  task :environment do
    AssetSync.configure do |con|
      con.fog_provider = 'AWS'
      con.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
      con.fog_directory = ENV['aws_bucket']
      con.aws_access_key_id = ENV['aws_access_key']
      con.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['aws_secret_key']
      con.prefix = "assets"
      con.public_path = Pathname("./public")   
    end
  end

 desc "Precompile assets"
 task :precompile => :"assets:environment" do
   AssetSync.sync
 end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i didnt quite understand the process in your last answer for my previous question, this one i do understand though. Regarding the ENV vars sent to heroku, i only need to add the ENV yes? things like fog_provider should be taken care of within my AssetSync Block?

Comment: @Richlewis I've added a bit to the answer, but it's up to you what you put in ENV. I tend to stick as much as possible in nowadays, one via a config file that's in source control, and any sensitive info I put in a `secret_settings` file that isn't in source control. Almost anything you'd hardcode, I stick in the ENV. It's so convenient, why not?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to split this into different questions. This makes it easier to help you. As for your first question: I assume you didn't put the `env.rb` under version control?

**Why are your env vars not being picked up by Sinatra?** Because you configure Fog in the Rakefile, and Simatra never sees that file. It's used by rake only.

I'd suggest you put the Fog configuration into a third file and `require` that in both Rakefile and Sinatra app.

Comment: yes env.rb is in my gitignore file,so fog is set like so con.fog_directory = ENV['applecatering' ?

Comment: Could I just put the whole task in a separate file?

Comment: Thanks, I have moved the config into a separate file and requiring it, locally everything is fine. COuld i ask why we require this in the sinatra app itself?

Comment: As far as I understand, you need Fog configured for rake and Sinatra, right?

Comment: well i havent required in in my sinatra app file and it works locally, just having few issues with heroku at moment